# Using auto layout and systemLayoutSizeFittingSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have a really simple view that I cannot for the life of me figure out the problem. I have successfully used auto layout and `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` for fairly complex custom `UITableViewCells`. This is my first time using it for a `UIView` (to be used in a `UITableView.tableHeaderView`) and I cannot get it to work.

I have a simple label in the view that I want to cover the entire view. I have added the `Trailing`, `Leading`, `Top`, and `Bottom` constraints to the label against the parent's corresponding edges. When I do this, `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` computes the correct `height`, but I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb71d9a310 V:|-(5)-[UILabel:0x7fbb71df5120'Test Label']   (Names: '|':mailapp.MailTableHeaderView:0x7fbb71d2c490 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb71d2ebf0 UILabel:0x7fbb71df5120'Test Label'.bottom == app.HeaderView:0x7fbb71d2c490.bottom - 5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb71de31d0 V:[app.HeaderView:0x7fbb71d2c490(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb71d2ebf0 UILabel:0x7fbb71df5120'Test Label'.bottom == app.HeaderView:0x7fbb71d2c490.bottom - 5>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Now, if I remove the "bottom" constraint on the label, auto layout works correctly but now `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` returns 0.

What is the right way to make the constraints satisfy the auto layout engine but also to have `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` compute the correct size?

As I mentioned, the most baffling thing is that I have used this successfully for complex auto layouts, but I noticed all those were `UITableViewCells`. I'm not sure if there is a difference.

Comment: are you using UILayoutFittingExpandedSize ?

Comment: @Fonix no, I am using UILayoutFittingCompressedSize

Comment: try adding a height constraint to the label that is set to the smallest height you want the label to be, but then make the height constraint greater than or equal to

Comment: Try to add `yourHeaderView.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` in the initializer.

Comment: Try adding the bottom and right constraint with respect to self.view , also show the code for adding the constraints

Comment: Are you setting these constraints in code or in a XIB / Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, but I don't understand why. For the UITableViewHeader, I cannot do the typical auto layout thing for the view. That is, I have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be `true`. Effectively, I cannot use auto layout for the header view, and I have to set the frame manually.

Within the header view, I can use auto layout for the sub views successfully.

So my algorithm goes like this for constructing the `tableHeaderView`:

- Create the header view with any arbitrary frame
- Compute the constraints (of the header view's subviews)
- Set the `frame.width` of the header view to match the parent `tableView.frame.width`
- Layout the header view
- Use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to compute the height
- Update the header view's `frame.height`

This works for me. I was not able to get it to work if I created the header view with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Apple Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) the following appears to be setting a '0' height constraint on your HeaderView.

E.g.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbb71de31d0 V:[app.HeaderView:0x7fbb71d2c490(0)]>"
```

I would start by investigating this, as having a height of 0 will likely mess up your other label constraints for top and bottom spacing.